# Math operation with an array but having problems with negative numbers

Tags: arrays, vb.net, negative-number

I got a few arrays and I want to do the following math operation:

```
For i As Integer = 10 To 100
    TransmissionArray(i) = (maxFirstArray(i) - mintranArray(i)) / (maxSecondArray(i) - mintranArray(i))
    i = i + 1
Next
```

The problem is that sometimes `mintranArray(i)` has higher values than `maxFirstArray(i)` and `maxSecondArray(i)`. So the program crashes.
With `Try Catch` the program is not shutting down but I only get `TransmissionArray() = Nothing`.

Comment: What specific error are you getting when you use the `Try...Catch` statement? The issue isn't with the numbers being negative or positive when dividing (as long as the `mintranArray(I)` value is never zero). Sounds more like your `TransmissionArray()` is not initialized properly. Could you add the line where you declare the array?

Comment: Dim TransmissionArray() As Double .
I declared the other arrays also like this

Comment: As @RianBattle pointed out, the maths functions work fine even with negative numbers. If `(maxSecondArray(i) - mintranArray(i)` equals zero, your division will return `Infinity`. That won't throw an exception and won't be caught in your Try/Catch block, but it migh cause problems later on.

Comment: Do you realise that you are incrementing `i` by 2 each time round the `For` loop. The loop itself increments it by 1 and then you are adding 1 again at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your `TransmissionArray` isn't being initialized properly. If you just `Dim` it like this:

```
Dim TransmissionArray() As Double
```

Then it will be `Nothing`. If you try to assign a value to it in this way, you will get an exception. Normally you can insert a number in the parenthesis (`Dim TransmissionArray(10) As Double`) and you would have an array of length 10 that you could immediately start assigning values to. But, if you don't know the length before hand, I can think of two options that would work:

```
Dim TransmissionArray() As Double
For i As Integer = 10 To 100
    ReDim Preserve TransmissionArray(i)     'This will increase the size of the array to the value of i, the Preserve keyword also saves the data already stored in the array
    TransmissionArray(i) = (maxFirstArray(i) - mintranArray(i)) / (maxSecondArray(i) - mintranArray(i))
    'i = i + 1         'Commented this out...i is already incremented once each loop
Next
```

Or, switch to using a `List(Of Double)`:

```
Dim TransmissionArray As New List(Of Double)
For i As Integer = 10 To 100
    TransmissionArray.Add((maxFirstArray(i) - mintranArray(i)) / (maxSecondArray(i) - mintranArray(i)))
    'i = i + 1         'Commented this out...i is already incremented once each loop
Next
```

Note that the second method would make `TransmissionArray` 10 items less than the other arrays, due to the fact you are starting the `For` loop counter at 10, and just adding items to the list.

Comment: No problem @Photoniker, glad I could help out.